# How to change selective part of page based on user action in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a page which has two columns. One the left column are some links, which when clicked should show different elements on the right column.

This is similar to say the Gmail page, where the left side column has links like Compose, Inbox and so on. Clicking on each of it will change the other column view.

One option to do it is to have all elements on the right column but change the hidden property to make them visibile based on the link clicked. But this looks like a kludge.

Is there a much cleaner approach to doing it in Rails ?

Thanks.

Comment: Using ajax and rendering partials would be the way to go for this. When a user clicks a link, it gets sent to the server in an ajax request, the server replies with the html content of just the right column, and then the js sets the html of the right column to what it just received from the server.

Comment: So, will the logic be this way : create a partial with the left column. Say _col.html.erb . I would have to create a view for each action (like compose, inbox) and each view for those would render the _col.html.erb ? Wont that mean the complete page is getting regenerated again from the server ?